# T-SQL find differences

Tags: t-sql

I found Jeff Smith's solution which is displaying differences between two tables:

```
SELECT MIN(TableName) as TableName, ID, COL1, COL2, COL3 ...
FROM
(
  SELECT 'Table A' as TableName, A.ID, A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, ...
  FROM A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Table B' as TableName, B.ID, B.COL1, B.COl2, B.COL3, ...
  FROM B
) tmp
GROUP BY ID, COL1, COL2, COL3 ...
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

In my project I need to compare eg. col1 and col2 only, rest is used for another operations.
I tried to use

```
HAVING (COUNT(col1) = 1 and COUNT(col2) = 1)
```

but with no effect.

Could you please ptovide me solution which will do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get the values of `COL1` and `COL2` in `A` that do not exist in `B` using EXCEPT:

   ```
   SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM A
   EXCEPT
   SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM B
   ```
2. Use the results as a derived table to join them back to `A` and get all the columns:

   ```
   SELECT 'A' AS SRC, A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3...
   FROM (
     SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM A
     EXCEPT
     SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM B
   ) AS diff
   INNER JOIN A ON diff.COL1 = A.COL1 AND diff.COL2 = A.COL2
   ```
3. Similarly, use EXCEPT to get the values of `COL1` and `COL2` that exist only in `B`, and join the resulting set to `B` obtain complete rows accordingly.
4. Combine the two sets with UNION ALL:

   ```
   SELECT 'A' AS SRC, A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3...
   FROM (
     SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM A
     EXCEPT
     SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM B
   ) AS diff
   INNER JOIN A ON diff.COL1 = A.COL1 AND diff.COL2 = A.COL2

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 'B' AS SRC, B.COL1, B.COL2, B.COL3...
   FROM (
     SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM B
     EXCEPT
     SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM A
   ) AS diff
   INNER JOIN B ON diff.COL1 = B.COL1 AND diff.COL2 = B.COL2
   ;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are dropping the columns from the wrong place. You should drop it from the lists of columns instead of from the star:

```
SELECT MIN(TableName) as TableName, ID, COL1, COL2
FROM
(
  SELECT 'Table A' as TableName, A.ID, A.COL1, A.COL2
  FROM A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Table B' as TableName, B.ID, B.COL1, B.COl2
  FROM B
) tmp
GROUP BY ID, COL1, COL2
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

To keep the other columns in the result, you can use `MIN` (or friends) to keep them:

```
SELECT MIN(TableName) as TableName, ID, COL1, COL2, MIN(COL3), MIN(COL4), ...
FROM
(
  SELECT 'Table A' as TableName, A.ID, A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, A.COL4, ...
  FROM A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Table B' as TableName, B.ID, B.COL1, B.COL2, B.COL3, B.COL4, ...
  FROM B
) tmp
GROUP BY ID, COL1, COL2
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

Note that this doesn't work very well for certain situations. If two rows are identical in the two tables (including IDs), then it will find it as a difference even though it's not. Also, in this version, if you have multiple rows where `COL1` and `COL2` are the same, then this doesn't work well either. I would join the two tables together for a more robust comparison.

Comment: Yo're right, but I would like have other columns in the resut set - not only these which I want to compare.

Comment: @ironcurtain I've updated the answer so that you can keep the columns.